# how to edit this batch file to check if exe is running

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, terminal

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do start "" /b "%%i"
```

How would I edit that to see if the exe is running before I start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /r %%i in (*.exe) do tasklist|findstr /i /b /L /c:"%%~nxi" >nul&if errorlevel 1 start "" /b "%%i"
```

This performs a `tasklist`, sending the result to `findstr` which looks for a line that `/b` begins `/L` literally with `/C:` the string "%%i" `/i` regardless of case (dispose of any output). If `findstr` finds no matching string, set `errorlevel` to 1. The `if` statement detects when `errorlevel` is 1 or greater, so if not found, start it.

Comment: You could shorten it up a bit using conditional execution as well. `for /R %%i in (*.exe) do tasklist|findstr /i /b /L /c:"%%i" >nul ||start "" /b "%%i"`

Comment: Doesn't work because %%i is a path to the exe, not the .exe name itself so it will return false because tasklist|findstr only returns the exe name and not path

Comment: OK - fixed (insert `~nx` before `i` in the `findstr` string to select name and extension only.

Comment: @FamilyFamily, in your free time read the help for the `FOR` command.  It will show you all the modifiers you can use to manipulate the FOR variable. It is at the very end of the help.